# .NET Forms Abstraction for WPF, Silverlight, Winforms, WebForms, etc

Tags: .net, silverlight, webforms, abstraction

Anyone know of a project(s) that seek to abstract form definitions on level higher than WPF, Silverlight, Winforms, WebForms, etc...

I'm working on a project where we are fixing up 16 somewhat simple WebForms. But we may convert (and probably will convert to WPF or Silverlight 3 to 4 months from now.

I'd rather define these forms once and be done with it. I'm willing to write a small DSL to help define forms, subforms, validation, links, and popups. I'm only looking to solve this for 80% or 90% of the forms. Four are very complicated and I'm willing to hand code these.

I guess I'm looking for something like what XUL had hoped to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Model View Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) comes in handy here (not ASP.NET MVC).

Your model and controller are standard classes. You should define a view as an interface IView because you will have to subclass from other parts of the Framework.

Comment: Agree. +1 This is the path I was heading down, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel if there was already a framework someone was working on.